# Disable https in livereload using rollup-plugin-livereload

Tags: rollupjs, livereload

So I a svelte and tailwindcss stack, doing rollup to bundle and it has a support plugin for livereload which is

```
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
```

On my rollup.config.js I have this snippet

```
    !production && livereload({watch: '../apps/firstarticleinspection', https: false}),
```

So that it doesn't load on https but I get error

```
GET https://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1 net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

which means it is still using https